# JAVA extended ASCII table usage

Tags: java, casting, char, ascii

in my app I need to get character from extended ASCII table that is shown on the image. But when I cast decimal values into char, I get different characters. What is the real value of these characters in JAVA. I dont write the character on console or in a file, just into the image.

```
private void generateAsciiMatrix()
{
    //32 - 255 are visible characters in ascii table
    for(int i = 32; i < 256; i++)
    {
        this.generateAsciiMatrix((char)i);
    }
}

private void generateAsciiMatrix(char letter)
{
    EBufferedImage character = new EBufferedImage(
            ImageClass.charToImage(letter, width, height));
    //...some code
}

public static BufferedImage charToImage(char c, int width, int height)
{
    BufferedImage off_Image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

    Graphics2D g2 = off_Image.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);  
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);  
    g2.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12)); 
    g2.drawString(Character.toString(c), 0, height);
    saveImage(off_Image, "code" + (int)c);
    return off_Image;
}
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry for my poor English :-)

[image]

Comment: The "extended ASCII table" is simply one mapping of "above ASCII" octect values to symbols on a terminal (or other rendering device). That is, it is just *one* of the many [code-pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) to map values of 128-255. That is, the character displayed depends on *what* displays it (e.g. assigned meaning and "font") and other applicable rules (e.g. codepage or "language") that it applies.

Comment: So how do I force my java program to use this code page ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters may be this can help you,.

Comment: I only write the characters on image, and then I work only with the image

Comment: @zdarsky.peter Add that to the question: how *are* the characters being written/rendered?

Comment: The table really looks like the [IBM OEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) character table.

Comment: You should at least accept an answer, zdarsky, even if it is just your own. If you find (my) answers or comments useful, please mod them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for this problem is that I manualy created a char array with those characters I needed

Comment: That's probably a good solution, but make sure you encode them as Unicode points (using \U) in your source code or you may have trouble when the code is interpreted as a different character set.

Answer (score 0):

Put the integer values in a byte array, then you can use `CharsetDecoder` to convert them into a String using `"Cp437"`.

Just a simple example:

```
Charset oem = Charset.forName("Cp437");
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(0xFF - 0x20 - 1);
for (int i = 0x20; i < 0xFF; i++) {
    if (i == 0x7F) {
        // skip DEL
        continue;
    }

    b.put((byte) i);
}
b.flip();
CharBuffer c = oem.decode(b);
System.out.println(c.toString());
```