# How to print the extended ASCII code in java from integer value

Tags: java, character-encoding, extended-ascii

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
int i=153;
int j=63;
System.out.println((char)i);
System.out.println((char)j);
}


OUTPUT:-
?
?
```

I have some ideas why is this strange output.. But can anyone give me some idea so that i can print the extended ASCIIs as well..

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA extended ASCII table usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826781/java-extended-ascii-table-usage)

Comment: Your code is working as expected. for e.g. `System.out.println((char)67);` will print 'C'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extended Ascii doesn't work in console!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100250/extended-ascii-doesnt-work-in-console)

Comment: Braj if you put some value beyond 127 then it will not work as expected, due to some ASCII limitation...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ASCII `153` (`0x99`) is different from Unicode `U+0099` (Control character).

## Solution

This program should do what you intend it to do:

```
public class ExtendedAscii {
    public static final char[] EXTENDED = { 0x00C7, 0x00FC, 0x00E9, 0x00E2,
            0x00E4, 0x00E0, 0x00E5, 0x00E7, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x00E8, 0x00EF,
            0x00EE, 0x00EC, 0x00C4, 0x00C5, 0x00C9, 0x00E6, 0x00C6, 0x00F4,
            0x00F6, 0x00F2, 0x00FB, 0x00F9, 0x00FF, 0x00D6, 0x00DC, 0x00A2,
            0x00A3, 0x00A5, 0x20A7, 0x0192, 0x00E1, 0x00ED, 0x00F3, 0x00FA,
            0x00F1, 0x00D1, 0x00AA, 0x00BA, 0x00BF, 0x2310, 0x00AC, 0x00BD,
            0x00BC, 0x00A1, 0x00AB, 0x00BB, 0x2591, 0x2592, 0x2593, 0x2502,
            0x2524, 0x2561, 0x2562, 0x2556, 0x2555, 0x2563, 0x2551, 0x2557,
            0x255D, 0x255C, 0x255B, 0x2510, 0x2514, 0x2534, 0x252C, 0x251C,
            0x2500, 0x253C, 0x255E, 0x255F, 0x255A, 0x2554, 0x2569, 0x2566,
            0x2560, 0x2550, 0x256C, 0x2567, 0x2568, 0x2564, 0x2565, 0x2559,
            0x2558, 0x2552, 0x2553, 0x256B, 0x256A, 0x2518, 0x250C, 0x2588,
            0x2584, 0x258C, 0x2590, 0x2580, 0x03B1, 0x00DF, 0x0393, 0x03C0,
            0x03A3, 0x03C3, 0x00B5, 0x03C4, 0x03A6, 0x0398, 0x03A9, 0x03B4,
            0x221E, 0x03C6, 0x03B5, 0x2229, 0x2261, 0x00B1, 0x2265, 0x2264,
            0x2320, 0x2321, 0x00F7, 0x2248, 0x00B0, 0x2219, 0x00B7, 0x221A,
            0x207F, 0x00B2, 0x25A0, 0x00A0 };

    public static final char getAscii(int code) {
        if (code >= 0x80 && code <= 0xFF) {
            return EXTENDED[code - 0x7F];
        }
        return (char) code;
    }

    public static final void printChar(int code) {
        System.out.printf("%c%n", getAscii(code));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printChar(153);
        printChar(63);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Ü
>   ?

As you can see from the output above, the intended character gets printed correctly.

---

## Extension of Concept

Also, I wrote a program that prints out the Unicode values for the extended Ascii. As you can see in the output below, a lot of characters have trouble being displayed as native `char`.

**Code:**

```
public class ExtendedAscii {
    public static final char[] EXTENDED = { 0x00C7, 0x00FC, 0x00E9, 0x00E2,
            0x00E4, 0x00E0, 0x00E5, 0x00E7, 0x00EA, 0x00EB, 0x00E8, 0x00EF,
            0x00EE, 0x00EC, 0x00C4, 0x00C5, 0x00C9, 0x00E6, 0x00C6, 0x00F4,
            0x00F6, 0x00F2, 0x00FB, 0x00F9, 0x00FF, 0x00D6, 0x00DC, 0x00A2,
            0x00A3, 0x00A5, 0x20A7, 0x0192, 0x00E1, 0x00ED, 0x00F3, 0x00FA,
            0x00F1, 0x00D1, 0x00AA, 0x00BA, 0x00BF, 0x2310, 0x00AC, 0x00BD,
            0x00BC, 0x00A1, 0x00AB, 0x00BB, 0x2591, 0x2592, 0x2593, 0x2502,
            0x2524, 0x2561, 0x2562, 0x2556, 0x2555, 0x2563, 0x2551, 0x2557,
            0x255D, 0x255C, 0x255B, 0x2510, 0x2514, 0x2534, 0x252C, 0x251C,
            0x2500, 0x253C, 0x255E, 0x255F, 0x255A, 0x2554, 0x2569, 0x2566,
            0x2560, 0x2550, 0x256C, 0x2567, 0x2568, 0x2564, 0x2565, 0x2559,
            0x2558, 0x2552, 0x2553, 0x256B, 0x256A, 0x2518, 0x250C, 0x2588,
            0x2584, 0x258C, 0x2590, 0x2580, 0x03B1, 0x00DF, 0x0393, 0x03C0,
            0x03A3, 0x03C3, 0x00B5, 0x03C4, 0x03A6, 0x0398, 0x03A9, 0x03B4,
            0x221E, 0x03C6, 0x03B5, 0x2229, 0x2261, 0x00B1, 0x2265, 0x2264,
            0x2320, 0x2321, 0x00F7, 0x2248, 0x00B0, 0x2219, 0x00B7, 0x221A,
            0x207F, 0x00B2, 0x25A0, 0x00A0 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (char c : EXTENDED) {
            System.out.printf("%s, ", new String(Character.toChars(c)));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Ç, ü, é, â, ä, à, å, ç, ê, ë, è, ï, î, ì, Ä, Å, É, æ, Æ, ô, ö, ò, û, ù, ÿ, Ö, Ü, ¢, £, ¥, ?, ƒ, á, í, ó, ú, ñ, Ñ, ª, º, ¿, ?, ¬, ½, ¼, ¡, «, », ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ß, ?, ?, ?, ?, µ, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ±, ?, ?, ?, ?, ÷, ?, °, ?, ·, ?, ?, ², ?,  ,

**Reference Table:** ([source](http://ascii-table.com/ascii-extended-pc-list.php))

```
Dec Hex Unicode     Char    Description
--- --- -------     ----    -----------------------------------
128 80  U+00C7      Ç   latin capital letter c with cedilla
129 81  U+00FC      ü   latin small letter u with diaeresis
130 82  U+00E9      é   latin small letter e with acute
131 83  U+00E2      â   latin small letter a with circumflex
132 84  U+00E4      ä   latin small letter a with diaeresis
133 85  U+00E0      à   latin small letter a with grave
134 86  U+00E5      å   latin small letter a with ring above
135 87  U+00E7      ç   latin small letter c with cedilla
136 88  U+00EA      ê   latin small letter e with circumflex
137 89  U+00EB      ë   latin small letter e with diaeresis
138 8A  U+00E8      è   latin small letter e with grave
139 8B  U+00EF      ï   latin small letter i with diaeresis
140 8C  U+00EE      î   latin small letter i with circumflex
141 8D  U+00EC      ì   latin small letter i with grave
142 8E  U+00C4      Ä   latin capital letter a with diaeresis
143 8F  U+00C5      Å   latin capital letter a with ring above
144 90  U+00C9      É   latin capital letter e with acute
145 91  U+00E6      æ   latin small ligature ae
146 92  U+00C6      Æ   latin capital ligature ae
147 93  U+00F4      ô   latin small letter o with circumflex
148 94  U+00F6      ö   latin small letter o with diaeresis
149 95  U+00F2      ò   latin small letter o with grave
150 96  U+00FB      û   latin small letter u with circumflex
151 97  U+00F9      ù   latin small letter u with grave
152 98  U+00FF      ÿ   latin small letter y with diaeresis
153 99  U+00D6      Ö   latin capital letter o with diaeresis
154 9A  U+00DC      Ü   latin capital letter u with diaeresis
155 9B  U+00A2      ¢   cent sign
156 9C  U+00A3      £   pound sign
157 9D  U+00A5      ¥   yen sign
158 9E  U+20A7      ₧   peseta sign
159 9F  U+0192      ƒ   latin small letter f with hook
160 A0  U+00E1      á   latin small letter a with acute
161 A1  U+00ED      í   latin small letter i with acute
162 A2  U+00F3      ó   latin small letter o with acute
163 A3  U+00FA      ú   latin small letter u with acute
164 A4  U+00F1      ñ   latin small letter n with tilde
165 A5  U+00D1      Ñ   latin capital letter n with tilde
166 A6  U+00AA      ª   feminine ordinal indicator
167 A7  U+00BA      º   masculine ordinal indicator
168 A8  U+00BF      ¿   inverted question mark
169 A9  U+2310      ⌐   reversed not sign
170 AA  U+00AC      ¬   not sign
171 AB  U+00BD      ½   vulgar fraction one half
172 AC  U+00BC      ¼   vulgar fraction one quarter
173 AD  U+00A1      ¡   inverted exclamation mark
174 AE  U+00AB      «   left-pointing double angle quotation mark
175 AF  U+00BB      »   right-pointing double angle quotation mark
176 B0  U+2591      ░   light shade
177 B1  U+2592      ▒   medium shade
178 B2  U+2593      ▓   dark shade
179 B3  U+2502      │   box drawings light vertical
180 B4  U+2524      ┤   box drawings light vertical and left
181 B5  U+2561      ╡   box drawings vertical single and left double
182 B6  U+2562      ╢   box drawings vertical double and left single
183 B7  U+2556      ╖   box drawings down double and left single
184 B8  U+2555      ╕   box drawings down single and left double
185 B9  U+2563      ╣   box drawings double vertical and left
186 BA  U+2551      ║   box drawings double vertical
187 BB  U+2557      ╗   box drawings double down and left
188 BC  U+255D      ╝   box drawings double up and left
189 BD  U+255C      ╜   box drawings up double and left single
190 BE  U+255B      ╛   box drawings up single and left double
191 BF  U+2510      ┐   box drawings light down and left
192 C0  U+2514      └   box drawings light up and right
193 C1  U+2534      ┴   box drawings light up and horizontal
194 C2  U+252C      ┬   box drawings light down and horizontal
195 C3  U+251C      ├   box drawings light vertical and right
196 C4  U+2500      ─   box drawings light horizontal
197 C5  U+253C      ┼   box drawings light vertical and horizontal
198 C6  U+255E      ╞   box drawings vertical single and right double
199 C7  U+255F      ╟   box drawings vertical double and right single
200 C8  U+255A      ╚   box drawings double up and right
201 C9  U+2554      ╔   box drawings double down and right
202 CA  U+2569      ╩   box drawings double up and horizontal
203 CB  U+2566      ╦   box drawings double down and horizontal
204 CC  U+2560      ╠   box drawings double vertical and right
205 CD  U+2550      ═   box drawings double horizontal
206 CE  U+256C      ╬   box drawings double vertical and horizontal
207 CF  U+2567      ╧   box drawings up single and horizontal double
208 D0  U+2568      ╨   box drawings up double and horizontal single
209 D1  U+2564      ╤   box drawings down single and horizontal double
210 D2  U+2565      ╥   box drawings down double and horizontal single
211 D3  U+2559      ╙   box drawings up double and right single
212 D4  U+2558      ╘   box drawings up single and right double
213 D5  U+2552      ╒   box drawings down single and right double
214 D6  U+2553      ╓   box drawings down double and right single
215 D7  U+256B      ╫   box drawings vertical double and horizontal single
216 D8  U+256A      ╪   box drawings vertical single and horizontal double
217 D9  U+2518      ┘   box drawings light up and left
218 DA  U+250C      ┌   box drawings light down and right
219 DB  U+2588      █   full block
220 DC  U+2584      ▄   lower half block
221 DD  U+258C      ▌   left half block
222 DE  U+2590      ▐   right half block
223 DF  U+2580      ▀   upper half block
224 E0  U+03B1      α   greek small letter alpha
225 E1  U+00DF      ß   latin small letter sharp s
226 E2  U+0393      Γ   greek capital letter gamma
227 E3  U+03C0      π   greek small letter pi
228 E4  U+03A3      Σ   greek capital letter sigma
229 E5  U+03C3      σ   greek small letter sigma
230 E6  U+00B5      µ   micro sign
231 E7  U+03C4      τ   greek small letter tau
232 E8  U+03A6      Φ   greek capital letter phi
233 E9  U+0398      Θ   greek capital letter theta
234 EA  U+03A9      Ω   greek capital letter omega
235 EB  U+03B4      δ   greek small letter delta
236 EC  U+221E      ∞   infinity
237 ED  U+03C6      φ   greek small letter phi
238 EE  U+03B5      ε   greek small letter epsilon
239 EF  U+2229      ∩   intersection
240 F0  U+2261      ≡   identical to
241 F1  U+00B1      ±   plus-minus sign
242 F2  U+2265      ≥   greater-than or equal to
243 F3  U+2264      ≤   less-than or equal to
244 F4  U+2320      ⌠   top half integral
245 F5  U+2321      ⌡   bottom half integral
246 F6  U+00F7      ÷   division sign
247 F7  U+2248      ≈   almost equal to
248 F8  U+00B0      °   degree sign
249 F9  U+2219      ∙   bullet operator
250 FA  U+00B7      ·   middle dot
251 FB  U+221A      √   square root
252 FC  U+207F      ⁿ   superscript latin small letter n
253 FD  U+00B2      ²   superscript two
254 FE  U+25A0      ■   black square
255 FF  U+00A0      no-break space
```

Comment: This is only valid for one code page, specifically CP437. That means these are the equivalences in a console on US-English windows, but won't work in UTF-8 xterm on Linux or CP850 console in Western Europe, etc. You have to know the encoding that your terminal is using.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `char[]` for `EXTENDED` rather than `int[]`?

Comment: @JamesSmith: Because `char` is 2 bytes whereas an `int` is 4 bytes. This translates to a smaller memory footprint. [ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Ty for your good answer. I changed my final code where I adapted your code the line: return EXTENDED[code - 0x7F]; to return EXTENDED[code - 0x80]; .- I am not sure it is an error here, or on my side with my input.

Comment: The results for me are one out. Input 128 -> output  ü

Answer (score 6):

"Extended ASCII" is nebulous. There are many extensions to ASCII that define glyphs for the byte values between 127 and 255. These are referred to as [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page). Some of the more common ones include:

- [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), the standard on original IBM PCs
- [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) also known as [Code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252), the encoding used for most Western European-language versions of Windows for everything but the console

You really need to know what [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) your terminal is expecting, otherwise you'll end up printing [garbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). In Java, you should be able to check the value of `Charset.defaultCharset()` ([Charset documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)).

There are many more ways to encode characters than just single-byte "extended ASCII" code pages. Unicode requires far more code points than 255, so there are various fixed-width and variable-width encodings that are used frequently. This page seems to be [a good guide to character encoding in Java](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String iChar = new Character((char)i).toString(); 
String jChar = new Character((char)j).toString(); 

System.out.println(iChar);
System.out.println(jChar);
```

Comment: You could probably easily do: `String.format("%c", i)`

Comment: i tried your sample, but for me the output is still `? ?` on eclipse console, Am I missing something?

Comment: @sakura You sure? 153 is some special character, 63 is "?", check [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), try to print 97 and 98, which should be "a" and "b"

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao Yes, Do I need some settings change on Eclipse, to see the special character printed using `sysout` on Eclipse console?

Comment: @sakura No, there nothing to do with the console, can you post your current code? I tried it, it works fine.

Comment: Java is interpreting the integer values as the Unicode their equivalent. You must map the Unicode values to the Extended ASCII values. See my response below.

Comment: I also tried in ecclipse and it is not coming... The problem is java supports ascii code 0-127. Beyond that it may show or not show in console.. Nothing to do with ecclipse setting..

Answer (score 0):

If this is a terminal encoding issue, I believe that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/362006/4828060

is a fast and straightforward way to bypass the problem. Just add 
-Dfile.encoding=some_encoding to the parameters of the java command,

e.g.
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 … MainClass